# How to manage multi-environment versonning with multi application using docker, traefik and git

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm writing a SAAS project with multi-applications:

- RestAPI
- Client

Everything is dockerized and managed by traefik, now my problems is I don't understand how to manage the versioning and what the best practices when you want to work with multi application.

My development environment looks like this:

```
  .
  ├── api
  │   ├── src/
  │   └── Dockerfile
  ├── client
  │   ├── src/
  │   └── Dockerfile
  ├── .env
  ├── docker-compose.yml
  └── Makefile
```

I can start all my service using make an that start all my services through docker-compose and traefik do his job but how to manage versioning I think it's not a good practice to make a common repository.

I think to dispatch my common .env to separate and add .env file to api folder and .env to client folder as to keep my application standalone but where to store my development environment with my makefile and my docker configuration with traefik network volume and so on, how to share this config with my team?

And if we keep our projects on their own repository that mean to pull every project separately to a common folder with treafik configuration pull this configuration and so on.

Maybe I'm wrong from the beginning and we don't have to use traefik like that but I'd to have one command to get all projects up to date.

Thanks for reading - hope someone can help me understand it :)

Comment: In SO we prefer a single question per post, rather than the 3 you have here so this will likely be closed soon. But... Swarm is deprecated (and awful), k8s is your only choice. Try k3d for local dev, it's quite easy, then you can migrate to managed k8s or k3s later on (k3d == k3s in docker). Versioning is hard, so is production.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I thought it was one and the same question in several blocks, I clean it out and keep the part I need ! Thank for your response :)